# Read data on specific condition using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, select, except

Hello I am using Visual studio 2015 with Entity Framework 5.0.

I have some data in table like following:

1

2

3

4

5

I want to read 1 and compare with 2,3,4,5
again read same but this time read 2 and compare with 3,4,5
now again read but this time read 3 and compare with 4,5
now again read but this time read 4 and compare with 5.

Is there any formula to read like read all data after 1 and again read data after 2 like 3,4,5 and read after data 3 read 4,5 and so on...

Comment: If you have sequencial ids (which from your exaple, you do), a simple way would be to order them, get the first and get all the other where id > than first.

Answer (score 1):

There's no mention on amount of data or if you have sequential identifiers, so I'm just assuming stuff.

If you need to do a compare on all.. a straightforward way you could go with this is just order the data and loop through it.

```
var entities = dbContext.Entity.OrderBy(e => e.Id).ToList();

foreach (var currentEntity in entities)
{
    // all other records except current...
    var allRecords = dbContext.Entity.Where(e => e.Id > currentEntity.Id).ToList();

    // do your compare stuff...
}
```

Since the data is already ordered, the foreach takes care of getting the next one for you. But if you don't have sequential Id's, you can still apply the same code but just apply sorting in another field that makes sense to you. e.g by date.

Or, if you want to do a "one-time" compare, meaning, you receive an Id and want to compare with the rest, then, of course you don't need a foreach. Just order by id and use the inside query or use Skip (as @Mohamed suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `id` of the row you want to compare with, in the following example, is hard-coded for illustration (5), you can do the following:

```
var subData = data.Skip(data.Count(x => x.Id <= 5)).ToList();
```

this code will get you a list of records containing all data after the row with Id = 5.